# What's the difference between the Julian and the Julian Ephemeris Day?

Tags: time

I'm making a code where I calculate the sun position in a given time. But I also want to learn astronomy with it. I'm following a .pdf to make the program, and in this .pdf it says

> The Julian Day (JD) is calculated using UT and the Julian Ephemeris
>   Day (JDE) is calculated using TT.

Is it the only difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it the only difference?

By definition, yes. It's important to keep in mind that the difference between TT and UT (UT1) is not constant.